# Nested ngFor not working properly in Angular 9

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm having a problem using nested ngFor cycles on an Angular 9 application. The last ngFor listed in the code below (code line 12) seems to work randomly only on arbitrary cycles of the main ngfor on the top row (code line 1).

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of PMRes; index as pmId;">
   <td>
     <div class="font-weight-bold">{{row.strategicProject.name}}</div>
     <div *ngFor="let subProw of this.pmEntity.pminfo.projects[pmId].subprojects; index as subPmId;" class="ml-3">{{subProw.name}}   
     (Local score: {{this.subPResults[pmId][subPmId].ranking*100}}%)</div>
   </td>
   <td *ngFor="let goal of row.goalPM">
     <div class="font-weight-bold">{{goal.goalRanking*100}}%</div>
     <div *ngFor="let subPres of this.subPResults[pmId]">{{subPres.ranking*goal.goalRanking*100}} %</div>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div class="font-weight-bold">{{contributionSum[pmId].valueOf()*100}}%</div>
    <div *ngFor="let subPresTot of this.subPResults[pmId]">{{subPresTot.ranking * contributionSum[pmId].valueOf() * 100}} %</div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

The results that i'm getting are the following. Sometimes the nested ngFor is only working on the first cycle of the main ngFor (see "strategic contribution" column) .[image: cycle 1]

Sometimes, it only works on the second data set:

[image: cycle 2]

What i'm not able to understand is how the exact same nested ngFor on code line 8 is working perfectly and displaying the results on both data sets consistently. I've tried to use different variable names for the two ngFor but i get no different results.

I've also tried to use some mock text to see if the `contributionSum[pmId].valueOf()` value was null for example, but i had no positive outcome as it's the ngFor that is not repeating itself/cycling more than once on an arbitrary random data set.

The console is showing no errors.
Edit: edited code and fixed some syntax as suggested on an answer, with no different outcomes

Comment: Any code behind that? ie getters that update their surrounding data in the middle?

Comment: not that i can recall, unfortunately it would be complex to post the whole application and i'd have to refactor it to make a working example. The data is loaded from a database, but the fact is that on the other columns it's already there and correctly loaded all the times (and i can't see why it just doesn't work on the last column the way it works on the others)

Answer (score 0):

the sintax of ngFor is, see [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description)

```
*ngFor="let variable of yourArray;"
```

Well, you can get the index, or the last or the first or ..., e.g.

```
*ngFor="let variable of yourArray;index as i;"
```

**not** exist some like

```
  <!--what is this "as subPresId"?????-->
 *ngFor="let subPres of this.subPResults[pmId] as subPresId"
```

Comment: You are right, that has been fixed now as:

<div *ngFor="let subPresTot of this.subPResults[pmId]">

However, the outcome is still the same and the second ngFor is not always cycling as it's supposed to be. Any suggestion? Where else should i check?
Thanks

Comment: The only I can see is your `contributionSum[pmId].valueOf()`, try -to convert to a number-:`subPresTot.ranking * (+contributionSum[pmId]) * 100- and check if in console you has an error-. You can try, only for check, write `{{pmId}}` in the td or <pre>{{subPrResults|json}}</pre>. NOTE: In the .html it's unnecesary write "this."

Comment: Thanks, i've also tried to just write {{pmId}} but i still weirdly get only some iterations for no reason. I think i've found a workaround instead, but i would like to know why it works. I've used:

`<div *ngFor="let subProw of this.pmEntity.pminfo.projects[pmId].subprojects; index as subPmId">{{this.subPResults[pmId][subPmId].ranking * contributionSum[pmId].valueOf() * 100</div>`

This way it works just fine, for some reason (so basically i'm using the same information but i'm iterating using the index... i find it very weird)